# Unwanted space behind emails in sql

Tags: sql, trim

I uploaded a spreadsheet to my database and some of the emails have spaces after them. I tried using Trim and RTRIM and none of them work. Then I came to think that maybe its some invisible hex code. This is what it looks like when I copy it out

This is what shows in my queue

> `"john.red@test.com\u00a0\"`

this is what it looks like in the database with the space

> `john.red@test.com`

how would I remove this space from all the fields?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove invisible characters in t-sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245664/how-to-remove-invisible-characters-in-t-sql).. Also look at [how-do-i-remove-non-breaking-spaces-from-a-column-in-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214848/how-do-i-remove-non-breaking-spaces-from-a-column-in-sql-server)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
UPDATE Your_Table
SET Your_Column = REPLACE(Your_Column, NCHAR(0x00A0), '')
```

`\u00a0` is the non-breaking space. You can remove it by replacing it with ''.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(0x00A0), '')' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

`\u00a0` is the [NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm). It's not a real space and `RTRIM` will not take it away.

You will have to use `REPLACE` to remove it:

```
REPLACE(<column-name>, NCHAR(0x00A0), '')
```